# Summing a given series of numbers in order to reset the summation as many times as possible algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, sum

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm (not necessarily a code) for solving the following question:

Given n positive and negative numbers that sum up to zero, we would like to find a starting index that will cause the cumulated sum to zero up as many times as possible.

It doesn't have to be in a specific manner, but the importance here is the efficincy- we want the algorithm/idea to be able to this in less then a qudratic "time complexity"

An example:
Given the numbers: 2, -1, 3, 1, -3, -2:

If we strat summing up with 2 (first index), the sum will be zero only once (at the end of the summation), but strting with -1 will yield zero twice during the summation.
The given numbers may have more than one "best index", but we would like to find at least one of these indexes.

I've tried doing it with binary search, but didn't make much progress- so any hints/help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute prefix sums. In terms of prefix sums, zeros are positions that have the same value of a prefix sum as the start position. So the problem is reduced to finding the most frequent element in the array of prefix sums. It can be solved efficiently using sorting or hash tables.

Here is an example:
Input: {2, -1, 3, 1, -3, 2}
Prefix sums: {0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 0}
The most frequent element is 2. The first occurrence of 2 is in the first position. Thus, starting from the second element yields optimal answer.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you, could you give an example?